# Quando si usano "egli", "ella", "esso", "essa", "essi", "esse" invece di "lui", "lei" o "loro"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns

Non riesco a capire in quali situazioni è necessario o conveniente usare i pronomi "egli", "ella", "esso", "essa", "essi", "esse" invece di "lui", "lei" o "loro". Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Senza togliere nulla alle buone risposte che sono state formulate, mi piacerebbe leggerne una che chiarisse per bene, separatamente, la *norma italiana classica* (“egli”, “ella” rispetto a “esso”, “essa” etc.), utile per leggere autori di un tempo e in generale per sapere come stanno le cose “in teoria”, e l'*uso attuale* (quasi solo “lui”, “lei”, “loro”, a parte usi letterari, burocratici o ricercati per qualche motivo).

Comment: Molto interessante è un [articolo sulla Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)

Comment: Se date un'occhiata a Grammatica Inglese (http://www.grammaticainglese.org/lezioni/2-I-pronomi-personali-soggetto.aspx) troverete che i pronomi personali soggetto - fortunatamente - sono ancora: io, tu, egli (ella, esso), noi voi, essi. Anche io naturalmente - nonostante l'età - ho adottato la via "facile" per il soggetto (lui, lei, loro), ma ho la fortuna (accompagnata dalla mia scelta) di avere ancora molte occasioni per poter usare quelli difficili ... un altro mondo. È un po' come l'uso di whom in inglese: provate a non usarlo nella City.

Comment: @DaG: Adesso che sto leggendo *La Locandiera* di Goldoni («Ella mi piace, le voglio bene, accomoderei con essa i miei interessi per tutto il
tempo di vita mia»), anche a me piacerebbe avere tale risposta qui.

Comment: Ormai, "l'Accademia della Crusca" legalizza diversi errori, magari, per non dispiacersi con chi che ha bisogno di una "codina" accanto alla "O" per sentirsi importante! Sarebbe meglio attenersi ai canoni della vera "Grammatica Italiana" coi pronomi soggetto di prima persona. Inammissibile, assolutamente, l'uso di: "ministra" che sa tanto di minestra e desta ilarità,"sindaca", ecc. e, men che meno, "attimino", tutti strafalcioni entrati nei dizionari, purtroppo. Questa non è evoluzione ma involuzione della nostra bella lingua, tanto martoriata anche da chi non dovrebbe!

Comment: @LidiaPeritore: Non è che annoi qualcuno, è che hai le idee poco chiare sulle funzioni e l'operato della Crusca, sull'evoluzione delle lingue umane, sul senso della loro grammatica (che non ha “canoni”, ma va studiata scientificamente, come i pianeti e le cellule), sull'uso delle maiuscole e così via. In bocca al lupo.

Comment: "La mia diletta città potrebbe benissimo fare a meno di me, ma sono io che non posso fare a meno di essa. Essa che mi scorre nelle vene e che amo." (BernardinoTelesio)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Gianni. Il tuo post non era una vera risposta alla domanda e, per questa ragione, è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 9):

**Egli, ella, essi ed esse**, come suggerisce [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Egli&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CEgli%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Begli%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEgli%3B%2Cc0), sono stati quasi completamente rimpiazzati da **lui, lei e loro**, tuttavia è possibile utilizzarli in contesti molto formali, oppure se si desidera conferire un sapore di "antico" a livello stilistico: infatti, fino a pochi decenni fa, *lui, lei e loro* erano considerati un errore se utilizzati in funzione di soggetto, e si raccomandava l'uso di *egli, ella, essi ed esse*.

Diverso discorso va fatto per **esso ed essa**, che vengono spesso utilizzati per riferirsi a sostantivi neutri (come oggetti ed animali). Si usano sia "essi" ed "esse" che "loro" per indicarne il plurale.

Comment: Infatti, la forma soggetto del pronome femminile di terza persona singolare era *ella*.

Comment: @DaG grazie, nel rispondere alla domanda non mi sono reso conto che avevo dimenticato di citarlo. Ho aggiornato la risposta

Comment: E per riferirsi a sostantivi neutri (oggetti, città, idee, sentimenti...)  in plurale, si usa "essi" o "esse"?

Comment: @Charo sì, ma sento spesso usare anche "loro": ho aggiornato la mia risposta

Comment: Anch'io aggiungo "ella" al titolo della domanda.

Answer (score 5):

In generale, **esso**/**essa** si usano solo per gli oggetti (e anche in quel caso si tende a formulare le frasi in modo da evitare di usare questi pronomi). Per gli animali, dipende dal grado di "umanizzazione" che vuoi esprimere, comunque praticamente sempre si usa **lui/lei**.

Altra questione è quella riguardante l'uso di **egli/ella** vs. **lui/lei**. La tendenza è decisamente verso l'uso di **lui/lei** in tutti i casi, soggetto incluso, relegando **egli/ella** a contesti prettamente poetici o letterari.
Per quanto riguarda il plurale, direi che **loro** è più comune di **essi/esse**, anche se forse la disproporzione non è così grande come nel caso del singolare.

Da notare che, molto tempo fa, **egli/ella/essi/esse** erano riservati per l'uso in funzione di soggetto, e **lui/lei/loro** in funzione di complemento. Oggi la lingua si è evoluta, e anche [**la Crusca**](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/soggetto) riconosce **lui/lei/loro** come soggetto.

Comment: E per riferirsi a sostantivi neutri (oggetti, città, idee, sentimenti...)  in plurale si usa "essi" o "esse"?

Comment: Sì, in teoria sì, ma si tende a evitarli perché suonano un po' strani e/o antiquati.

Comment: Nota che *lui/lei/loro* si sono sempre potuti usare come soggetto in frasi come *me l'ha detto lei*, *ci andarono loro* o, in genere, quando il soggetto è posposto al verbo.

Comment: @egreg vero, lo menziona anche l'articolo della Crusca.

Answer (score 5):

I **pronomi personali soggetto di 3a persona** sono:

- **egli**, **lui** ed **esso** per il singolare maschile;
- **ella**, **lei** ed **essa** per il singolare femminile;
- **loro**, **essi**/**esse** per il plurale.

[image]

[Fonte della tabella: Enciclopedia Treccani online](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

*Egli* e *lui* si usano con riferimento alle persone (*lui*, specialmente nella lingua parlata, si riferisce anche agli animali e alle cose); *esso* è usato per animali e cose. La stessa differenza non si riscontra tra *lei* ed *essa*; la forma *essa* è riferita anche a persona, ma il suo uso è sempre meno comune e ha un carattere letterario o regionale. Analogamente a *lui*, la forma *lei* si riferisce, specialmente nella lingua parlata, anche agli animali e alle cose. Le forme del plurale, *essi*/*esse*, servono per indicare tanto le persone quanto gli animali o le cose; *loro* è usato con riferimento alle persone (e, specialmente nella lingua parlata, anche agli animali).

Nell’uso comune i pronomi soggetto **egli** (singolare maschile), **ella** (singolare femminile), **essi** (plurale maschile) ed **esse** (plurale femminile) appaiono di uso limitato; in particolare, **ella** è ormai desueto e usato solo in contesti burocratici o altamente formali (in questo secondo caso, in riferimento ad alte cariche religiose o civili) e di solito si accompagna all’uso delle maiuscole di reverenza:

- **Ella** comprenderà, signor Presidente.
- **Ella**, Reverendissimo Vescovo, è stat**a** chiarissim**a**. (Con il pronome allocutivo *Ella* si ricorre più spesso alla concordanza femminile )

Arcaico è l'uso di *egli* in frasi impersonali e come soggetto neutro: "*egli è che cominciavammi allora i tocchi di una malinconia dolce, profonda*" (Dossi, *Opere*).

In funzione di soggetto *lui* (singolare maschile), *lei* (singolare femminile) e *loro* (plurale sia maschile, sia femminile) sono nettamente prevalenti e il loro uso, *a lungo avversato dalla grammatica normativa*, **è ormai pienamente accettato anche in contesti formali**.

Il linguista *Marcello Durante* ha evidenziato che egli e lui non sono semplici doppioni. Infatti *egli* (con *ella, essa, essi, esse*) serve a richiamare il nome di una persona già citato in precedenza e comunque ricavabile dal contesto (è un pronome anaforico), mentre *lui* (con *lei, loro*) si avvicina piuttosto al valore di *quello* (*quella, quelli, quelle*), in quanto non surroga soltanto il nome, ma richiama, allude concretamente alla persona. Tuttavia *egli* è piuttosto raro anche in quelle scritture il cui protagonista dell'azione narrata viene citato più volte nel corso del tempo. Ancor più raro di *egli* è il corrispondente *ella* o *essa*, ché fuor di Toscana *ella* ha generalmente sapore di letterarietà, ed *essa* non è riuscito ad imporsi dovunque anche perché già adempie all'ufficio, non condiviso da *egli*, di designare la cosa inanimata: ciò spiega il successo della variante *lei*.

In particolare **sono obbligatore le forme lui, lei, loro** anziché *egli, ella, essi, esse*:

- quando si vuole mettere in evidenza il soggetto, nel qual caso il pronome si pone dopo il verbo: *ci va lui*, *l'ha detto lei*, *sono stati loro*;
- quando il pronome è in funzione di predicato: *non sembrava più lui*, *se io fossi lei*, *ma noi non siamo loro*;
- dopo *come* e *quando*, cioè in complementi di paragone: *sei bravo come lui*;
- tra *ecco* e *che* relativo: ecco che lui non ci crede;
- nelle contrposizioni: *lui dice di si, lei di no*;
- quando il verbo è al gerundio o al participio: *essendoci lui, eravamo più tranquilli*;
- nelle esclamazioni ellittiche: *contento lui, cntenti tutti*;
- in altre espressioni mancanti del verbo ed espressioni olofrastiche: *chi è stato? lui*;
- dopo *anche, neanche, pure, neppure, nemmeno*: *nemmeno loro lo hanno visto*.

Suggerisco infine di leggere l'articolo del Prof. Sabatini sul sito della Crusca [*Egli e lui soggetto*](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/soggetto).

Il **pronome di terza persona in funzione di complemento**, quando indica una persona diversa dal soggetto, assume le forme **lui** per il singolare maschile, **lei** per il singolare femminile, **loro** per il plurale maschile e femminile: *vado con lui, non mi dimenticherò di lei, fai prue affidamento su di loro.*

Le forme **esso**, **essa**, **essi** ed **esse**, in funzione di complemento, si ri riferiscono soltamente agli animali e alle cose, raramente alle persone (con riferimento agli animali si usano anche, specialmente nella lingua parlata, *lui, lei, loro*); **il loro uso ha poi un'ulteriore limitazione**: *possono adoperarsi come complemento indiretto, cioè preceduti da una proposizione, ma non come complemento oggetto*. Per esempio:

- *l'aereo è il mezzo più veloce, con esso è facile raggiungere paesi lontani*
- *è una trama troppo debole, su di essa è impossibile costruire un romanzo*

ma in funzione di complemento oggetto si userà la forma atona **lo**:

- *vedi quel libro? portamelo* (e non *portami esso*)

Il pronome di terza persona in funzione di complemento è **sé** quando ha valore riflessivo, cioè quando si riferisce al soggetto della frase:

- *ha troppa stima di sé*,
- *pensano solo a sé*.

La forma atona del pronome personale di terza persona è **si** (=*sé* e *a sé*) nell'uso riflessivo: *si guardarono allo specchio, il cane si leccava le ferite*.

Alla terza persona singolare e plurale, quando non si riferisce al soggetto della proposizione, il pronome presenta una duplice serie di forme:

- lo/la singolare maschile/femminile per il complemento oggetto
- li/le plurale maschile/femminile per il complemento oggetto
- gli/le singolare maschile/femminile per il complemento di termine
- loro plurale maschile e femminile per il complemento di termine

Per quanto riguarda la collocazione, noteremo che **loro**, a differenza degli altri pronomi atoni, è posposto al verbo. La collocazione proclitica (cioè anteposta al verbo) è assai rara nella lingua di oggi; può verificarsi occasionalmente nel linguaggio burocratico in presenza di un participio: *le competenze loro spettanti, le pene loro comminate.*

**Loro** può inoltre essere interposto tra ausiliare e participio:

- *si recarono al ristorante che era stato loro indicato*
- *le agevolazioni che hanno loro consentito di attenuare le perdite*

e, in generale, tra verbo reggente e verbo retto:

- *il rifornimento di carburante ha fatto loro perdere il vantaggio acquisiti*

Nell'italiano di oggi è sempre più frequente l'uso di **gli** al posto di **loro**: *li invitai a casa e gli offrii un aperitivo* (in luogo di *offrii loro*).

Ma si trova ampiamente attestato anche in tutta la tradizione letteraria:

- *Chi si cura di costoro a Milano? Chi gli darebbe retta?* (A. Manzoni, I promessi sposi)

A favorire l’uso di *gli* al plurale c’è anche il fatto che il pronome *loro* è bisillabico (e dunque tonico, a differenza di tutti gli altri pronomi personali di questo tipo) e dev’essere sempre posto dopo il verbo.

**Fonti**

- *Treccani*
- *Serianni*, Grammatica Italiana
- *Dardano, Trifone*, Grammatica Italiana con elementi di linguistica
- *Renzi, Salvi, Cardinaletti*, Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione

Comment: "Esso", "essa", "essi" ed "essa" possono avere anche funzione di complemento, no? Come, per esempio, in questa frase tratta de *La Locandiera* di Goldoni: «Ella mi piace, le voglio bene, accomoderei con essa i miei interessi per tutto il tempo di vita mia».

Comment: Sì certo, ho limitato la risposta al caso di pronomi personali soggetto ma se voui aggiungo anche il caso di pronomi personali complemento.

Comment: Se potessi farlo, sarebbe davvero interessante.

Comment: Sì certo, aggiorno il post.

Answer (score -5):

Dalla terza elementare ti scrivo un esercizio che mi rimase impresso:
lui (soggetto) mangia la mela (di chi?) di ella complemento
Lei (soggetto) mangia la mela (di chi?) di egli complemento

i complementi non vanno mai sottintesi, i soggetti puoi anche farlo per rendere più scorrevole il testo:

Diede uno schiaffo a Camilla = Le diede uno schiaffo = Egli diede uno schiaffo a lei

Comment: “di ella”? “di egli”? Sicuro?

Comment: Il vocabolario Treccani però afferma che "egli" e "ella" sono forme usate solo come soggetto e solo riferite a persone.