# Qual è la differenza tra "essi" e "loro?"

Tags: synonym

Quando devo usare "essi" invece di "loro?" Qual è la differenza?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this one: http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/4069.

Answer (score 0):

Come accade per "egli/ella" e "lui/lei", nell'uso corretto, "essi" andrebbe usato come soggetto e "loro" come complemento. Nella prassi, l'uso di "essi" è di fatto limitato, in ogni caso, alla sola lingua scritta, in cui comunque non se ne fa largo uso, ad esempio sui social network.

[una prima fonte](http://www.iluss.it/free_iluss/Gram+Exe1/pronomi-complemento.html), [altra fonte](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/soggetto)

Cfr. [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/4069/quando-usare-egli-ella-esso-essa-essi-esse-invece-di-lui-le) altra domanda.

Comment: Che cos'è “Iluss”?

Comment: Sembra essere una fonte di informazioni interessante sulla lingua italiana, senza per forza dover citare i prolissi, per quanto estremamente colti, articoli dell'Accademia della Crusca. Se non erro, è un sito finalizzato all'insegnamento della Lingua agli stranieri.

Comment: Il problema è che io personalmente non so chi siano (e mi sembra neppure tu: “sembra essere”): una fonte ignota potrebbe contenere errori, scherzi, omissioni, testi plagiati altrove. Non sto insinuando che ciò valga per “Iluss”, ma dobbiamo accettare a scatola chiusa la loro “autorità” senza sapere chi sono. Tutto qui. Grazie per la risposta e benvenuto!

Comment: Grazie per il benvenuto e per il consiglio, ne farò tesoro in futuro, essendo un nuovo utente alle prime armi. Di solito faccio attenzione alle fonti, questa volta, mi sono basato sul fatto che quanto scritto da loro collima con la mia esperienza personale, ed è per questo che ho citato anche l'Accademia. Però, a ripensarci è vero, neanche io li conosco, semplicemente, ho visto che danno un'esposizione convincente, ma anche semplice, di una versione dei fatti che ritengo plausibile.